# Incrementing score value through time - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on simple 3d mobile game. At the end of gameplay I would like to create Panel with simple increasing/decreasing score values.

I'm base my increasing code on @empty answer from topic: [Unity3D: Speed up highscore count up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119578/unity3d-speed-up-highscore-count-up/54120307)

The problem I have is that when I run this script in most basic way (in Update with no conditions - it works):

```
t = Mathf.MoveTowards(t, 1.0f, Time.deltaTime/scoreAnimationLength); // Move t towards the second value
int scoreToDisplay = (int)Mathf.Lerp(0, 1000f, t);
scoreText.text = "Score " + scoreToDisplay.ToString();
```

but when I add it on GameObject that is active not from beginning or add it in condition like

```
if(GameManager.instance.gameOver == true) 
{
    //code
}
```

it just doesn't work - I mean the changing score text works, but without animation - it just display final value.

I believe that problem is with Time.deltaTime, tried to work with my own deltaTime

```
myDeltaTime =  Time.time - lastUpdate;
lastUpdate = Time.time;
```

but it doesn't work.

How I can make working this animation in delayed conditions?

Comment: Your `myDeltaTime` is going to be exactly identical to `Time.deltaTime`. As for why your code isn't working, you need to show more of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition says `if(GameManager.instance.gameOver == true)`, so when the game is over, it executes the code and update the value.

So what you have to do is, inside some update or co-routine you have to increase the value of score, best choice would be co-routine. Don't use thread(personal opinion). And in another update method you can just write `scoreText.text = "Score " + scoreToDisplay.ToString();`.

Back in the co-routine, when `if(GameManager.instance.gameOver == true)` gives you true, just destroy the co-routine.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you use LeanTween. (You can import it from the Asset Store).

You can adjust time to complete and different animations in just one line of code. Here is an example how you can actually do it.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using TMPro;

    public class Score : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public TextMeshProUGUI ScoreText = null;

        int currentScore = 1000;
        float howManySecondsToComplete = 3;

        void Start()
        {
            LeanTween.value(0, currentScore, howManySecondsToComplete).setOnUpdate((float val) =>
            {
                ScoreText.text = ((int)val).ToString();
                Debug.Log("Elapsed Time: " + Time.time);  
            });
        }   
    }
```

[image: Example]